# Invalid February date using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to format my selected date. When I've selected a February date, moment.js has returned 'invalid date':

```
moment('28/02/2018').isValid(); //returns false
```

But, when I've selected a March date, moment.js has returned a valid date:

```
moment('01/03/2018').isValid(); //returns true
```

Can someone say me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a date in the format of `DD/MM/YYYY`, you'll have to describe the format when parsing:

```
moment('28/02/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY').isValid(); // returns true
```

Note: The second example works, but is not a March date, it's January 3rd. That should be a clue as to why the first example doesn't work.

When you provide an input that is not recognizable, [moment will throw a warning in your console](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/).

Comment: In my case, I get the date in Brazilian format (DD/MM/YYYY) and i want to convert to 'YYYY-DD-MM' format. The second date in Brazilian format is 1st March.

Comment: I've tried to use `moment('28/02/2018').format('YYYY-DD-MM')` and it has returned me 'Invalid date'. It's strange because when I've tried `moment('05/02/2018').format('YYYY-DD-MM')`, it has returned me the date that I want.

Comment: Because the original parse of `28/02/2018` is invalid, and therefore trying to format it after-the-fact wont work. You need to provide a format to tell moment what you initially want. If you want to convert it for display later, you can use `.format` just like you have: `moment('05/02/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYY-DD-MM');`